# how to increase APEX REST inbound call cpu time limit

Tags: apex, apexrest, cpulimit

I have created a Apex Rest class, which is publicly exposed.

I wanted to test cpu time limit for inbound call and found that it is **16 -20** sec.

Is there any way by which I can increase cpu time limit for inbound call.

Comment: I think the real question here is, what is your code doing that makes it consume so much CPU time? (and can your code be improved?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are 2 ways to achive this.

1. Inbuilt Salesforce: Use heavy for loops and iterative oprations that CPU would reach peak limit.
2. Use a Rest Endpoint, make callouts to that endpoint frequently till the time you wanna test the scalability of your rest endpoint. The endpoint can be any, you can use request bin to test. https://requestb.in/

Comment: I have already tested as I mentioned in question. sorry if my question failed to provide correct information. I need to know how to increase inbound call limit :)

Comment: No you cannt buddy. :) Governer limits are in place so that we dont over utilize more than whats shared with you